# Power Query expand list of records

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is a very basic question but can't find an answer to this. I am using the power query editor but most of the fields in it are greyed out and I cannot edit the table as I want to. See below:

[image]

My objective here is to expand the individual records and I have already seen some youtube videos where this can be achieved by adding a new column but apparently that field has been greyed out. The link that I am entering in power query is this:

https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/mlb/scores/json/TeamSeasonStats/2018?key=fa737459090340c0a435e6bf25b15baf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Transform .. To Table ... to ungrey most of the options
Then you can expand.

Sample generic code you can try out by pasting into home ... advanced editor...

```
let Source = {[ a = 1, b = 2 ] , [ c = 3 ] , [ a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ]},
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList)
in Expand
```

[image]

Or in your specific case

```
let Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/mlb/scores/json/TeamSeasonStats/2018?key=fa737459090340c0a435e6bf25b15baf")),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList)
in Expand
```

[image]